# Html load css if detects mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

```
<link media="only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px)" href="smartphone.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5)" href="iphone.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

am I doing it right ? or there is better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Cole mentioned, you can check the userAgent. This is some javascript that you can use to detect if the userAgent is an iphone. ([Source](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/redirect-mobile-devices/))

```
<script language=javascript>
<!--
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
//Change the css
}
-->
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at te user agent and load the appropriate one with php. Using that however limits you to 320-480. Blackberrys are like 240x320 I think (at least the 9xxx series)